# Does this mixture between pronunciations have a name?

Tags: phonetics, accent

If a person pronounces a word with the sound /ɒ/, for example *not*, but says /kɑr/ instead of /kɑː/, does this *mixture* receive a name?

Comment: It would probably help to give a few more details, if you have them. Are you thinking of a situation with a non-native speaker, or a native speaker? Either can show mixed accents, but with native speakers, another possible explanation aside from mixing that may be likely is that the accent simply developed naturally to be intermediate to other more well-known accents.

Comment: @sumelic It's related to a situation with non-native speakers. Namely, learners. They tend to sound American but when it comes to articulating sounds like *not, block, lock*, they use the /ɒ/ sound which produces the *mixture* I mentioned.

Comment: It would be helpful to casual observers of this question if it included a brief description of what those sounds are phonetically, since not everyone knows the notation.

Comment: Can you edit to give more details? Who is mixing what? I don't see any mixing.

Answer (score 2):

There are some regional English accents that naturally have /ɒ/ in 'not' and /ɑr/ in 'car' but I assume you are talking about someone that has an accent that combines features of more than one region, country, social stratum etc. - e.g. RP and General American.

I do not know of a specific linguistic term that refers to this, but the term *colouring* is sometimes used to refer to the influence of one accent on another, e.g. 'General American with some RP colouring' or 'regionally coloured RP'. *Synthesis* or *synthetic* might be an appropriate term to describe an accent that shares an equal number of features from different accents, but it does not, as far as I am aware, bear this specific linguistic meaning.

Comment: The term "creole" is sometimes used to refer to a "collision" between languages, but linguists would probably be fairly picky about how it is applied.

Comment: _Creole_ is applied to a merger of _languages_ (one stage of evolution along from a _pidgin_, I think), but not to a merger of accents.